# Where to declare queues in separate event handlers

Tags: c#, winforms, queue, private

Hi I am trying to use the queue function in my program for a mini game that receives X,Y,Z acceleration from an accelerometer.

However I don't know where I should or how I should declare the queue to make it accessible in two separate event handler.

As you can see I tried multiple attempts and declaring it in both the private event handlers was my last attempt.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my current code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ConnectedComPortUpdate();
            serialPort1.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

            comboBox1.DropDown += comboBox1_DropDown;

        }

        private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectedComPortUpdate();
        }

        private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int xAccel;
            int yAccel;
            int zAccel;

            Queue<int> myXQueue = new Queue<int>();
            Queue<int> myYQueue = new Queue<int>();
            Queue<int> myZQueue = new Queue<int>();

            while( myXQueue.Count!=0 && myYQueue.Count!=0 && myZQueue.Count!=0 );
            {
                xAccel = myXQueue.Dequeue();
                yAccel = myYQueue.Dequeue();
                zAccel = myZQueue.Dequeue();

                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                                {
                                    XAccel.Text = xAccel.ToString("000");
                                    YAccel.Text = yAccel.ToString("000");
                                    ZAccel.Text = zAccel.ToString("000");
                                }));

            }

        }

        private void ConnectedComPortUpdate()
        {
            //Clears COM List
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            //Accesses System Port Information and Adds it to the ComboBox
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToArray());
            //Selects the last and "first" device
            try
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please plug in your tiny stick");
                comboBox1.Text = (" ");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
                    butPortState.Text = "Disconnect";
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected port '{0}'", serialPort1.PortName));
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a serial port from the drop down list");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                    comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                    butPortState.Text = "Connect";
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int currentDataByte = 0;
            int byteToRead;
            int xAccel = 0;
            int yAccel = 0;
            int zAccel = 0;

            Queue<int> myXQueue = new Queue<int>();
            Queue<int> myYQueue = new Queue<int>();
            Queue<int> myZQueue = new Queue<int>();

            while (serialPort1.IsOpen && serialPort1.BytesToRead != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    byteToRead = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                }
                catch
                {
                    byteToRead = 0;
                }
                if (byteToRead == 255)
                {
                    currentDataByte = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentDataByte++;
                    switch (currentDataByte)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            myXQueue.Enqueue(byteToRead);
                            xAccel = byteToRead;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            myYQueue.Enqueue(byteToRead);
                            yAccel = byteToRead;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            myZQueue.Enqueue(byteToRead);
                            zAccel = byteToRead;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use tags for the platform (WP8, Win8 ?)

Comment: "Where to put this?" - Surely not in `Form1`'s code behind.

Comment: Why's that not in Form1? Sorry I am complete beginner in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You would need the queues to be declared at the class/instance level:

```
// These can now be used in all event handlers...
Queue<int> myXQueue = new Queue<int>();
Queue<int> myYQueue = new Queue<int>();
Queue<int> myZQueue = new Queue<int>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ConnectedComPortUpdate();
    serialPort1.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

    comboBox1.DropDown += comboBox1_DropDown;

}

private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConnectedComPortUpdate();
}

private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int xAccel;
    int yAccel;
    int zAccel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer to this question (or even the question itself) is C# specific necessarily.  Consider the question "Where should I declare variable X"  The answer is almost always "In the narrowest scope possible that's accessible every place that needs to use variable X"

In your case, the answer may be "At the class level"

Alternatively, if you were to program in a more functional style the answer may be "Reconsider the structure of the program so that X can be passed as a parameter to the functions that need it".  Most C# event handler have a place where you can stick a "user state" object so that it can be passed along from event source to event handler.

The answer would be the same in C, C++, java, etc. 
(Perhaps this should be a comment, but I'm afraid it's a bit long)